# Is there an efficient way to select from NgRx state the same data in multiple places & handle the many subscriptions for that select?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ngrx, ngrx-store

I am still a beginner in NgRx and I have this case where I want to select part of the NgRx state (called **actionStatus**) in many places to check for a condition, but everytime I want that **actionStatus** I have to subscribe to it *creating new subscriotion* that needs to be unsubscribe from, also my way creates a lot of *repatative code*.

I feel like there is something that I am missing here

myComponent.ts

```
actionStatus$: Observable<number>;
subscription1: Subscription;
subscription2: Subscription;
subscription3: Subscription;

ngOnInit() {
    this.actionStatus$ = this.store$.select(fromApp.selectActionStatus);
}


// repeatative code in actions 
doAction1(): void {
    this.subscription1 = this.actionStatus$.pipe(take(1))
        .subscribe((actionStatus: number) => {
     // some code
    });

}

doAction2(): void {
    this.subscription2 = this.actionStatus$.pipe(take(1))
        .subscribe((actionStatus: number) => {
     // some code
    });

}


doAction3(): void {
    this.subscription3 = this.actionStatus$.pipe(take(1))
        .subscribe((actionStatus: number) => {
     // some code
    });

}


// a lot of subscriptions to unsubscribe from
ngOnDestroy(){
    this.subscription1.unsubscribe;
    this.subscription2.unsubscribe;
    this.subscription3.unsubscribe;

}
```

Comment: event actions should trigger `store.dispatch` operations - not selects or subscribes. remember, selectors are live pipes

Comment: just a few suggestions here: 1-refactor the repetitive part into a class, 2-use angular async pipe (that would relieve you from handling all the unsubscriptions).

Comment: @pixelbits I have a logic that depends on the state (actionStatus) to decide whether I will dispatch an action or not, also some of these functions does not change the state at all so they are not triggering any action related to ngrx and will not dispatch any action, like hiding the an element from the dom or changing the style.

Comment: @Isaiahiroko Thanks for the suggestions. 1-How can I refactor them into a class ? the code is already in a component class, and I want the state at this very place. plz tell me if u have a specific way in mind. 2- How I am gonna use it here? I think the async pipe is used only with the template code, unless u mean the async wait javascript ??

Comment: @ZiadAamer then you don't need to subscribe to that in a `doAction()` event handler. Just put that code in `ngOnInit()`

Comment: @pixelbits you mean that I should define one subscription in the ngOnInit() and whenever the state change I can set the value in variable e.g. actionState: number, that can be accessed globally in that class & whenever I read from it I will be having the latest value from in the state and no need to subscribe individually in those functions, this is what you mean right? Thanks for ur help.

Comment: @ZiadAamer, that is right

Comment: @pixelbits Thanks sounds better than my approach, also can I ask you a question? When I select an object from that state will I be referencing to a readonly object in the state and I need to deepCopy it or will it give me a new another copy ?

Comment: It will return you a read-only copy of state. You shouldn't modify it after you select it because it is read-only. You shouldn't need to deepCopy it either. If you need to modify the state, then dispatch an action to the store.

Comment: @pixelbits I need to modify the object before showing it in UI for example or sending a request to the backend with small tweaks, but I don't want to change the state at all, so if it is a readonly object I have to deepCopy it to be able to change things in it, is that correct?

Comment: Yes, that's right